# PHP Correct way of stopping to load the view if not logged in

Tags: php, authentication

I have a website in PHP and a log in page. which is loaded when the class is construct if the session "Caisse_login" is not created. I have seen a bug which i have fixed with exit(), but I wanted to know if there is any other way of doing it.

here is the beginning of my class:

```
class caisses extends controller{

    public function __Construct(){

        $this->caisseModel = $this->model('caisse');

        if(!isset($_SESSION['Caisse_login']) OR $_SESSION['Caisse_login']==FALSE){
            
            $this->login();
            exit();
        }
    }
```

everytime an url is entered it will call the associated method. so if i use the following URL:

caisselive/en/caisses/showTable/3

it will therefore create the class above caisses, and the following method:

```
public function showTable($tableId = 0){

    // control if there is at least one table
    if(!$this->caisseModel->countTable()){

        flash('Transaction', 'No any table have been created', 'alert alert-warning');
        redirect('caisses/transaction');

    }else if($tableId==0){
        $data = [
            'table' => $this->caisseModel->getAllTable(),
        ];

        $this->view('caisses/tableShow', $data);
        


    }else{

    // control if the ID provided is an existing table
        if(!$this->caisseModel->getTempTablebyID($tableId)){

            flash('Transaction', 'The table does not exist', 'alert alert-warning');
            redirect('caisses/showTable');
        }else{

    //Display the table
                $totalPrice = 0;

                $productsQuery = $this->caisseModel->getTempTableProducts($tableId);

                $tempTable = $this->caisseModel->getTempTablebyID($tableId);
                
                $i=0;                   
                $k=0;
                $totalPricePaid=0;
                $productsPaid = null;
                foreach($productsQuery as $products_1){
                // control if it has already been paid
                    if($products_1->paid==0){
                        for($j=0;$j<$products_1->qty;$j++){

                            $products[$i]['productName'] = $products_1->product_name;
                            $products[$i]['productID'] = $products_1->id_product;
                            $products[$i]['transactionId'] = $products_1->id;
                            $products[$i]['rebate'] = $products_1->percentage;
                            $products[$i]['rebateID'] = $products_1->id_rebate;
                            $products[$i]['rebateName'] = $products_1->name;
                            $products[$i]['qty'] = 1;
                            $products[$i]['price'] = $products_1->price_s;
                            $products[$i]['priceTotInt'] = number_format($products_1->price_s * 1 * (1-($products_1->percentage/100)), 2);

                            $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $products[$i]['priceTotInt'] ;

                            $i++;
                        }
                //create the list of what it has already have been paid
                    }else{
                        $productsPaid[$k]['productName'] = $products_1->product_name;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['productID'] = $products_1->id_product;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['transactionId'] = $products_1->id;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['rebate'] = $products_1->percentage;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['rebateID'] = $products_1->id_rebate;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['rebateName'] = $products_1->name;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['qty'] = $products_1->qty;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['price'] = $products_1->price_s;
                        $productsPaid[$k]['priceTotInt'] = number_format($products_1->price_s * $products_1->qty * (1-($products_1->percentage/100)), 2);

                        $totalPricePaid = $totalPricePaid + $productsPaid[$k]['priceTotInt'] ;
                        
                        $k++;
                    }
                }

                $data = [
                    'products' => $products,
                    'productsPaid' => $productsPaid,
                    'dateTable' => $tempTable->date,
                    'nameTable' => $tempTable->nameTable,
                    'tableId' => $tableId,
                    'rebate' => $this->caisseModel->getAllRebate(),
                    'totalPrice' => number_format($totalPrice, 2),
                    'totalPricePaid' => number_format($totalPricePaid, 2)
                ];

                $this->view('caisses/tableShowDetail', $data);
                
        }
    }
}
```

what happens if the person is not loged in, it will load the 2 views, as explained I have kinda fixed it with the exit() when the class is constructed, but I am wondering if there is not a better way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1):

There are different options. If you use a framework, you could use a method to redirect this request to another controller. Another option is to set a boolean to indicate that this user is not logged in and you process this parameter in your controller.
The easiest solution you have already implemented, just an exit, but this could cause some issues if you need to execute something on the end of every operation in a controller.